# I am trying to get my android app to upload multiple images into firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I read different articles on how to go about it and i use a particularly easy one that i have no idea why i did not think of that in the first place, It was to loop the method that contains the function of uploading a "single image", looping it will then repeat the method according to the number of images to be uploaded, but i am finding something rather troubling here, maybe its my code or something but i have no idea why, during the loop, it loops according to the number of images alright, but when i check the firebase storage, i find just an image at the directory which is always the last image i selected, so i am thinking maybe my code deletes existing images in the directory and then save incoming images therefore deleting all previous images and leaving only the last one ( just a thought though) i am attaching my code now, i am so sorry, but i sometimes make mistakes in attaching codes, please bear with me.

The OnActivityResult method:

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == gallerypick && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "multiple images selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    imageuri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    inputproductimg.setImageURI(data.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri());
                }
            } else {
                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Single image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imageuri = data.getData();
                    inputproductimg.setImageURI(imageuri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

method that calls the upload image function

```java
addproductbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Validateproduct();
            }
        });
    }

    private void Validateproduct() {
        Pname = inputproductname.getText().toString();
        Pdescription = inputproductdesc.getText().toString();
        Pprice = inputproductprice.getText().toString();

        if (imageuri == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "One image must be selected at least", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Pname) || TextUtils.isEmpty(Pdescription) || TextUtils.isEmpty(Pprice)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Images will take turns to save, Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    storeproductinfo(imageuri, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the upload image function itself

```java
private void storeproductinfo(Uri imageuri, int i) {
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
savecurrentdate = currentdate.format(calender.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat currenttime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
savecurrenttime = currenttime.format(calender.getTime());
productkey = savecurrentdate + savecurrenttime;

final StorageReference filepath = Pimagesref.child(gendercategoryname).child(categoryname)
        .child(Pname + productkey).child(this.imageuri.getLastPathSegment() + gendercategoryname + categoryname + productkey + ".jpg");
progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
final UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(this.imageuri);
filepath.putFile(this.imageuri).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                String message = e.toString();
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(newProduct.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(newProduct.this, "Image uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Task<Uri> urltask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        downloadUrl = filepath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        return filepath.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                            progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(newProduct.this, "Product Image URL has been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Saveproductinfo();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

}
```

maybe the upload method wasnt necessary but im only being thorough, please kindly help in pointing out my mistake(s)
Thank you.

Comment: You call your upload function at button click. And it uploads one file which uri is imageuri. This imageuri is the last assigned one of the for loop.

Comment: `looping it will then repeat the method according to the number of images to be uploaded, ` But in the loop you are uploading nothing. But your idea is ok.

Comment: i am sorry, but in the loop contains the method of my upload function and the method is to run according the number of times of the loop, right ?, I stand to be corrected though.

Comment: I already corrected you. In the loop you are uploading nothing.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much